# HDC type in ctypes in Python

Tags: python, camera, ctypes

I've got .dll lib and .h file when I've got a declaration of function which I want to use:

```
BOOL CxStartVideo(HDC WindowDC,int DeviceId);
```

I want to use this function in Python using ctypes.I have a DeviceId from other function in this .dll file, but I really don't know how I could create a HDC type variable to use it as an argument.

Above code fragment is an API of SMX 150 camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions here without a working C example to base it on, so this is an untested example to work with:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

def boolcheck(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ValueError(f'{func} returned {result}')

def nullcheck(result, func, args):
    if result is None:
        raise ct.WinError(ct.get_last_error())
    return result

dll = ct.CDLL('./thedll')
CxStartVideo = dll.CxStartVideo
CxStartVideo.argtypes = w.HDC, ct.c_int
CxStartVideo.restype = w.BOOL
CxStartVideo.errcheck = boolcheck

user32 = ct.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
GetDesktopWindow = user32.GetDesktopWindow
GetDesktopWindow.argtypes = ()
GetDesktopWindow.restype = w.HWND
GetWindowDC = user32.GetWindowDC
GetWindowDC.argtypes = w.HWND,
GetWindowDC.restype = w.HDC
GetWindowDC.errcheck = nullcheck

hwnd = GetDesktopWindow()
hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd)
result = CxStartVideo(hdc)
```